# How to redirect to new URL in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I've changed the URL structure of my WordPress post (not page) from:

```
example.com/archive/post-id
```

to:

```
example.com/post-name
```

so when any user open  `example.com/archive/post-id`, i need to redirect to  `example.com/post-name`

some site take my old link and put it in his site, so any user click in this link, its open old link. its nit true.

i need to redirect to new link

I'd like to redirect the old structure /post/ to the new one via .htaccess, or plugin.

**Edit:**
i search for my problem and see this code:

```
add_action( 'import_done', 'wordpress_importer_init' );

add_action( 'init', 'old_links' );
function old_links(){
    add_rewrite_rule('^archives/([^/]*)/?','index.php?p=$matches[1]','top');
}
```

now i need to open new link instead of old link.

when open

`example.com/archive/post-id` i need to replace it with `example.com/post-name`

Answer (score 0):

You can place this rule **before your existing WP rules** (just below `RewriteBase` line):

```
RewriteRule ^archive/(.+)$ $1 [NC,R=301,L]
```

Comment: iam edit my file but stil not page found 

`# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^archive/(.+)$ $1 [NC,R=301,L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress`

Comment: I clearly mentioned in my answer **before your existing WP rules** but still have mu suggested rule after WP rules. Place my rule just below `RewriteBase / ` line.

Comment: i do that but still not page found 

`<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^archive/(.+)$ $1 [NC,R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>`